# How to access SSAS datapump url from UNIX box with windows authentication on

Tags: ssas, datapump, olap4j

I'm trying to access SSAS through the data pump URL (http://SERVERNAME/OLAP/msmdpump.dll) with windows authentication on.

1) I was able to access the data pump URL through olap4j using windows machine. But how do i pass username and password for authorization purpose? (It seems like windows authentication details are parsing to endpoint behind the seance.)

2) But when i used the same code base on the MAC it throws an error saying "Unauthorized Access" (401 error). How do i access this URL (data pump) from LINUX OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure but there seems to be no trace that this is possible from linux.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/714ca9cc-aa80-4e3f-b080-febc5189249c/ssas-connectivity-from-javalinux-using-msmdpumpdll?forum=sqlanalysisservices

https://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-76926.html

For HTTP access and related configuration see the following documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0